# calling pdflatex from command line

Tags: upgrade, latex

I just updated to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and installed Latex according to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373). I added

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH    
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/info
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/man
```

but when I want to compile a document (i.e. `test.tex`) calling `pdflatex` nothing happened. If I added the complete path `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux`, then I could call `pdflatex` and compile `test.tex`. I checked `/usr/bin` and `pdflatex`, `xelatex` is listed there, but not available as a command.

Further research led me to [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-latex-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and I though I'd need to install `texlive-extra-utils` in order to directly call `pdflatex`. Now I can do this, but when I want to compile `test.tex` I get lots of errors about missing packages.

So what I assume happened is, that I installed the complete texlive package via the [instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373), but somehow adding the path variables didn't work. With the second [method](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-latex-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux), I just installed the ability to call `pdflatex` in the command line, but it "doesn't know" that I have a complete `texlive` installation in `/usr/local`.

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you need the latest texlive, the first procedure you have followed is the right one. However, the second installation procedure installs some older texlive. You now have two parts of different versions. If you do not need the latest texlive, I would suggest to install it with `sudo apt install texlive` or `sudo apt install texlive-full`. You can just install it and it should work. If not you may have to find a way to remove the latest version installed manually. Uninstalling non working version would probably be a sensible decision anyway.

Comment: Great, thanks. I assumed something like this happened. I checked the versions and it's only a year difference, so I'll go with the second route you mentioned and have apt install everything.

Answer (score -1):

Install Latex Packages by following command.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra texlive-latex-extra
```

Comment: Those are old versions of packages. OP wants to use the latest version of TeXLive

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1168689)